# Regards to textbox validation

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I wrote a simple javascript function for validating  textboxes  in a aspx page

```
     <body>
     <script type="text/javascript" > 
      function checkTextbox(sender, target) {

      if (document.getElementById(sender).value  < document.getElementById(target).value) {
            var lbl = document.getElementById('<%=lbl_Outlet_Message.ClientID %>');
            lbl.style.display = 'block';
            lbl.value = "Enter Slab To Value should be greater or equals to From Value ";
        }

    }
</script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
 <asp:Label ID="lbl_Outlet_Message" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txt_from_02" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox> 
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_to_02" runat="server" onKeyUp="checkTextbox(this,'txt_from_02')">
</asp:TextBox>

</form>
</body>
```

When I am running  aspx page, It is giving following error
"0x800a01a8 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object required"
I'm unable to know where I went wrong.

Comment: Enable debugging for JavaScript in your browser and you will get to the root of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The function `checkTextbox` expect the sender as id but you are passing the current object using `this`, you should use `this.id` instead of `this` or change the if condition by directly assessing value property of current object instead of pass the current object to `document.getElementById`

*Change*

```
if (document.getElementById(sender).value
```

*To*

```
if (sender.value
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById` can't find the ASP.NET control with just an ID name as a result `document.getElementById(target)` returns null and that throws an exception.

You should use `clientID` property.

Try changing this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_to_02" runat="server" onKeyUp="checkTextbox(this,'txt_from_02')">
```

To:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_to_02" runat="server" onKeyUp="checkTextbox(this,'<%=txt_from_02.ClientId %>')">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using document.getElementById function but you are not passing the Id of the textbox. So you are getting the error. You are passing the whole object of textbox by writing "this". So document.getElementById(sender) is not actually getting the id. Try with below solution and your code will work perfectly :

```
<body>
 <script type="text/javascript" > 
  function checkTextbox(sender, target) {

  if (document.getElementById(sender.id).value  < document.getElementById(target).value) {
        var lbl = document.getElementById('<%=lbl_Outlet_Message.ClientID %>');
        lbl.style.display = 'block';
        lbl.value = "Enter Slab To Value should be greater or equals to From Value ";
    }

}
```